# Does Go store objects in map by value or as pointers?

Tags: go

I have the following map:

```
var conns map[string]Conn
```

Where as you know, `Conn` is a custom type. And my map stores values of types Conn, as the declaration shows.
For storing them in a map, I do this:

```
conns["127.0.0.1"] = Conn{}
```

But my question is does Go, under the hood, store a pointer to the `Conn` object or it actually stores the value?

Comment: You are storing a copy of the struct; the `Conn` type is not a pointer.

Comment: How it works "under the hood" is an implementation detail, and may differ by implementation. What matters, from a language spec standpoint, is the behavior. And a `map[string]Conn` is a map of objects, whereas `map[string]*Conn` is a map of pointers to objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`struct`s are stored by value. Accesses to `conns["127.0.0.1"]` will give you a *copy* of the `Conn` struct.

If you try to modify the struct like this, the struct at `conns["127.0.0.1"]` will remain unchanged until you overwrite the map entry with the newly modified struct:

```golang
c := conns["127.0.0.1"]
c.x = y

// `c` now contains different content to `conns["127.0.0.1"]`!

// To ensure conns["127.0.0.1"] is updated, either overwrite or use a point.
conns["127.0.0.1"] = c // overwrite
```

This is why when you modify the struct, the struct in the map remains unchanged until you overwrite the map entry with the new struct.

Instead, you can store the pointer to the struct. This allows direct modification of the struct.

So if you change the type of `conns` from `map[string]Conn` to `map[string]*Conn`, the first two lines of the above code would update the struct in the map.

More information can be found here: https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/07/interface-semantics.html